# I want to show data from Firebase Database into HTML table

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase

*I am currently having trouble retrieving data from the Firebase Real-time Database and want to show it in HTML table. I would like to ask some help,I currently have a project/task that is all about the back end. I've decided to use Firebase as a database in my web application. I can now send data to the database but I have a problem, I can't retrieve the data from Firebase to the web application. I am planning to retrieve data and display it in my table (HTML).*

```
  $(document).ready(function () {



        var config = {

            authDomain: "digital-student-diary.firebaseapp.com",
            databaseURL: "https://digital-student-diary.firebaseio.com",
            projectId: "digital-student-diary",
            storageBucket: "",
            messagingSenderId: "573866105673"
        };
        firebase.initializeApp(config);

        const database = firebase.database();
        const databaseReference = database.ref().child('school/teacher');

        databaseReference.on('child_added', snap => {
            JSON.stringify(snap.val());


            var name = snap.child('teacherName').val();
            var email = snap.child('teacherEmail').val();
            var dob = snap.child('teacherDateofBirth').val();
            var phone = snap.child('teacherPhone').val();
            var cnic = snap.child('teacherCnic').val();
            var city = snap.child('teacherCity').val();
            var street = snap.child('teacherStreetAddress').val();
            var gender = snap.child('teacherGender').val();



            var tableRef = document.getElementById('tableBody');

            tableRef.append('<tr><td>' + name + '</td><td>' + email + '</td><td>' + dob + '</td><td>' + phone + '</td><td>' + cnic +
                '</td><td>' + city + '</td><td>' + street + '</td><td>' + gender + '</td></tr>');
        });




    });
```

**view-teacher.html**

**This is my view teacher file with a basic HTML table and the table body has the ID "tableBody" which I used for the referencing table.**

```
<div class="content mt-3">
    <div class="animated fadeIn">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12">
                <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-header">
                        <strong class="card-title">List of Teachers</strong>
                    </div>
                    <div></div class="card-body">
                    <table class="table">
                        <thead class="thead-dark">
                            <tr>
                                <th>Name</th>
                                <th>email</th>
                                <th>DOB</th>
                                <th>Phone</th>
                                <th>CNIC</th>
                                <th>City</th>
                                <th>Street</th>
                                <th>Gender</th>

                            </tr>
                        </thead>

                        <tbody id="tableBody">

                        </tbody>
                    </table>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div><!-- .animated -->
</div><!-- .content -->
```

*This is the output of my code*

[image: output]

Comment: please erase your apiKey immediately and then change it in your admin console.

Comment: Do not share your API key here please. I have edited it out but you will have to change it from your firebase settings regardless.

Comment: try `tableRef.innerHTML =`

Comment: You should look into using a js framework, such as Angular, that can generate templated data from Firebase easily.

Comment: tableref.innerHTML retrieving me a single record

Answer (score 0):

you don't need the

```
<script>
```

tag in the table body. screenshot if the page structure in web tools would be more helpful to diagnose the problem. the  structure seems right.